# NetDecoder broken for Input Depth 4?

Tags: neural-networks

I am trying to interpret a 4-tensor net output as a 3-tensor of class probabilities :

```
net = NetInitialize@NetChain[{LinearLayer[{2, 2, 2, 2}]},
"Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", "InputDepth" -> 4}], "Input" -> 1]

set = {{1} -> {{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}}, {2} -> {{{2, 
  1}, {2, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {1, 2}}}}
```

If I call this net on the set I get the correct output dimensions (3-tensor)

```
Dimensions[net@set[[1, 1]]] 
-> {2,2,2}
```

However, if I try to use NetTrain it expects a 4-tensor at the output port:

```
NetTrain[net, set] 

-> NetTrain::invindim: Data provided to port "Output" should be a list of 2*2*2*2 4-tensors.
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Best,
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `SoftmaxLayer` as the last layer in your net.

```
net = NetChain[
  {
   LinearLayer[{2, 2, 2, 2}],
   SoftmaxLayer[]
   },
  "Input" -> 1,
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", "InputDepth" -> 4}]
  ]
```

According to the documentation:

[image]

This is not problem right now because `NetDecoder["Class"]` doesn't check that all values are nonnegative and their sum is 1. But this may change in the future.

```
NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]@{-20, -10}
(* 1 *)
```

The error message means that `NetTrain` tried to attach `MeanSquaredLossLayer`. And for classification task you need `CrossEntropyLossLayer`.

[image]